# Do Different ArcGIS for Desktop License Levels Process Faster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, performance, arctoolbox, license

At my job, I have access to all three levels of ArcGIS licensing on my computer.

Does the license you are using in ArcMap make a difference on the speed of ArcMap?

I'm pretty sure that the drawing of the map isn't affected, based on tests I've done myself. But, it really does seem like some of the ArcToolbox tools do work faster in ArcInfo. I'm just trying to either validate my suspicious or prove I am going a bit crazy.

Comment: No. License only makes certain components not register (and thus not show on menus). You are going a bit crazy :)

Comment: Haha, good too know! I was leaning towards my sanity leaving me!

Comment: In my experience, using ArcInfo is a tiny bit slower (because I have to yell at each my colleagues to shut down ArcMap so I can grab the single floating license...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my personal experience, no.

Looking at the product matrix, there is also nothing to indicate they would groom their performance as such.

http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis10-functionality-matrix.pdf

I would suggest running some test cases with the *same data*, *stored locally*, on the *same computer*, with *different licenses* in order to identify if the tools 'actually' run faster.

Your statement about the different levels 'seem[ing]' to run faster implies to me that you haven't actually timed the processes.

Comment: I did some tests over the weekend and it really seems to me that there is no difference whats so ever really. So in the end I am just working too much and losing my marbles. Thanks a ton for the replies folks!

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: My view may not reflect my employer's.

I've worked for Esri since 1994, mainly on ArcInfo workstation then ArcGIS Desktop. I've never heard of any work to change performance depending on current license level. It's always been a yes/no functionality setting.

Could there be something? I guess, but honestly, we're not that Machiavellian.

Comment: Thanks, Melita. Jiggering performance like this is not unusual or Machiavellian, because complex software sometimes requires complex recoding to take advantage of larger systems, multiple processors, etc. For instance, [Stata](http://www.stata.com/products/which-stata-is-right-for-me/) has differential licensing according to RAM and MP capabilities and *Mathematica* licenses according to the number "kernels" that are allowed to run in parallel. I wouldn't be surprised or even disappointed to see Arc* software structured in a similar way in the future.

Comment: We can add Microsoft to the list. SQL Server is highly dependant upon license levels in terms of RAM, CPU Cores, and less importantly disk space.  I do remember though processing parallel tasks with even ArcEngine and ArcInfo licenses without seeing a degrade in efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not matter at all..I worked on Esri support previously.

It does not matter at all..System settings are only matters and the license type i.e concurrent/single use etc..

If you are using concurrent licensing and the license is on server (lot of security stuff) then it will take few seconds as compare to single use licenses..

Enjoy the ArcGIS : )